# Does visual c++ 2013 have an option (like gcc's -std=c++98) to use an older dialect?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have some code that compiles in Visual C++ 2013, but am told it doesn't build in VC++2010 (as it uses a subtle c++11ism).
Of course, the thing to do is for me to test with both compilers, but... 
isn't there a way to turn off c++11 in visual C++ 2013 and have it only accept c++08, as I think gcc's -std=c++98 option does?

Comment: No, VC++ doesn't support it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. You will need an older compiler for an older language conformance level.

Comment: Note that VC++2010 is already C++11-ish...

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the only way is to change the `Platform Toolset` to `Visual Studio 2010 (v100)` in Project -> Properties -> General. Once you change it, you will run VC++2010 compiler under VS2013.